# Zakat on Advance Salary

Tags: ramadan, zakat

Bismillah,

I have received INR 4.2 lakhs as advance salary from my organization as I wanted to make a down payment to book a property in March 2022.

Due to some personal reasons I was not able to book the same property and my advance salary remained back in my account.

I have postponed my plan to buy property by 6 months from now.

I am eligible for zakat as my saving meets the nisab amount.

Will I also need to pay Zakat on my advance salary which is there with me.

Note-I calculate my zakat in first week of Ramadan every year.

Comment: Zakat is on savings that are with you for a complete hijri year this is independent of a specific date, because the due depends on when the saved money reached the nisab.

Comment: @Medi1Saif could you please elaborate if possible. Jazak Allah Khairn for the reply.

Comment: Well what I've said is basic knowledge which you may also find in Wikipedia.